# Actualizar Datasource de un JDBCTemplate sin redesplegar con Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, webservice, spring-jdbc

Estoy realizando un webservice con Springboot que se conecta a varias bases de datos de terceros mediante conexiones jdbc usando JDBCTemplate.

El problema es que varias de estas bases de datos tienen passwords que se modifican cada pocos días y necesito que se actualicen estas contraseñas en caliente para no dejar sin servicio el endpoint mientras actualizo el application.properties y redespliego.

Mi solución pasa por actualizar las contraseñas en el datasource y refrescar el bean pero no encuentro como puedo modificar el pass en caliente.

Para refrescar la configuracion del bean en Hikari vamos a usar Spring Actuator (/refresh)

Application.properties

```
tercero1.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@IP:PUERTO:SID
tercero1.datasource.username=user
tercero1.datasource.password=pass
tercero1.datasource.maximum-pool-size=2
tercero1.datasource.driver.class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

BDConfig(@Configuration):

```
   @Bean(name = "TERCERO1")
    @ConfigurationProperties("tercero1.datasource")
    public DataSource terceroDataSource(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }



    @Bean(name="tercero1")
    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate tercero1(@Qualifier ("TERCERO1") DataSource datasource) {
        
        return new JdbcTemplate(datasource);
    }
```

DAO(@repository):

```
    @Autowired 
    DataSource dataSource;

    @PostConstruct
    private void initialize(){
        setDataSource(dataSource);
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("tercero1")
    private JdbcTemplate tercero1;
```

¿Es posible entonces actualizar un datasource? Sino fuese posible, ¿solo bastaría con un usar `tercero1.setDatasource(nuevoDataSource)` y posteriormente usar el /refresh de Spring Actuator?

Un saludo y muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es tener un servicio REST expuesto por ejemplo en el cual crees el nuevo nuevoDataSource con la contraseña y lo pases a la inyección de tercero1.setDatasource(nuevoDataSource) así no necesitas actualizar la propiedad `tercero1.datasource.password`

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la anotación @RefreshScope es justo lo que estás buscando, precisamente [en la documentación se pone como ejemplo un Datasource](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Greenwich.SR2/multi/multi__spring_cloud_context_application_context_services.html#refresh-scope):

> When there is a configuration change, a Spring `@Bean` that is marked
> as `@RefreshScope` gets special treatment. This feature addresses the
> problem of stateful beans that only get their configuration injected
> when they are initialized. For instance, if a **DataSource** has open
> connections when the database URL is changed via the Environment, you
> probably want the holders of those connections to be able to complete
> what they are doing. Then, the next time something borrows a
> connection from the pool, it gets one with the new URL.

Si no estás creando manualmente el datasource, quizá necesites añadir la clase en la entrada de las propiedades:

> If a bean is "immutable", you will have to either annotate the bean
> with @RefreshScope or specify the classname under the property key
> `spring.cloud.refresh.extra-refreshable`.

Comment: El problema no reside tanto en refrescar el bean sino en actualizar el datasource en caliente. Probaré lo que comentas y publico el resultado.
Gracias!

Comment: Yo estaba pensando en refrescar un bean que cumpla la interfaz `java.sql.DataSource`